# Length of line segment under matrix transform

Tags: matrices

> A matrix $$Q = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ -3 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ The points $A(a,2)$ and $B(4,-a)$ are transformed into $A’$ and $B’$, respectively. The length of $A’B’$ is $\sqrt{58}$. Find possible values of $a$.

---

I have done this by mapping A and B and then forming an equation and I get the correct answers of 3 and 31/5

However when I try to do this by considering the length scale factor it does not work and I do not know why:

Area scale factor = modulus of determinant of Q = 3

So I thought the length scale factor is $\sqrt{3}$. I’ve then made an equation using the fact that the length of the line segment AB is $\sqrt{58/3}$. Not sure why this does not give me the correct solutions?

Comment: This is because all lengths (directions) are not scaled equally by $A$. Consider the segment joining  origin and $(1,0)$. It gets mapped to segment from origin to $(2,-3)$ scaling the length by $\sqrt{13}$. However, the segment joining origin and $(0,1)$ gets mapped to segment between origin and $(-1, 0)$, resulting in a scale factor of $1$.

Answer (score 1):

The length of

$$A’B’=d((2a-2,-3a),(8+a, -12))=\sqrt{(a-10)^2+(-3a+12)^2}=\sqrt{58}$$

Then $(a-10)^2+(-3a+12)^2=58 \implies 10a^2-92a+244=58$ imply
$$a=3, \dfrac{31}{5}$$

The length for the factor $\dfrac{1}{3}$

$$A’B’=d\left(\left(\dfrac{2a}{3}-\dfrac{2}{3},-a\right),\left(\dfrac{8}{3}+\dfrac{a}{3}, -4\right)\right)=\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{a}{3}-\dfrac{10}{3}\right)^2+\left(-a+4\right)^2}=\sqrt{\dfrac{58}{9}}$$

Then $(a-10)^2+(-3a+12)^2=58 \implies 10a^2-92a+244=58$ imply
$$a=3, \dfrac{31}{5}$$

Answer (score 0):

There are uncountably infinitely many ways of transforming and even anisotropically scaling a space (an area) to give the same determinant. Just take the anisotropic scalings, then scaling the first axis by $1$ and the second axis by $3$ gives the same determinant as scaling the first axis by $9$ and the second axis by $1/3$, but in the first scaling the second axis increases and in the second scaling it decreases